# SCCM 2012 Manual Copy osd file to remote distribution point

Tags: sccm, system-center, distribution, windows

In our organization we have 1 site with 3 servers. 
Server A is the main server containing all roles.
Server B and C are distribution points.

These 3 servers are connected over wan, this works fine for the applications and such but Now I need to do a operating system deployment.

The problem is that the required files are too big and they are not being pushed to server B & C.

Is there a way to manually copy import the needed files to the remote DP's? Then i can do it with some sort of mobile media.

Comment: Do the logs indicate why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with prestaging.  I'm not 100% certain of the process with regards to Images but I know it works wonders with packages.

This article appears to go through what you need to do the pre-staging for your remote DPs:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/inside_osd/archive/2011/04/11/configuration-manger-2012-content-prestaging.aspx